# Minitest assertion failing on inspect

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, minitest

Whenever I try to assert_equal two objects, I always get errors like this:

```
   No visible difference in the User#inspect output.
   You should look at the implementation of #== on User or its members.
```

It's happened with Time and Array as well.
Minitest docs don't really say much on this either.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0, but I was using 2.2.0 and the same happened. Using latest minitest as well.

Also, I'm running Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Does this really happen for *all* objects, have you tried comparing really basic stuff like integers? Can you give us some examples?

Comment: Are you using a custom difftool?

Comment: It's actually just happening for Time, Array, and custom objects I've created, like the User class. I'm not using any custom tools.
Example:
`result = @service.run`
`result.must_equal(@users.get_single(1))`
Note: I've also tried assert_equal, and the same happens

Answer (score 12):

## About the message

This message, which kinda isn't an error, is shown when the assertion fails, but MiniTest fails to find a difference between the objects.

[Check out this method](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/master/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L57).

`diff` runs `#inspect` on the two objects and runs a diff tool on that. If there is no diff, this message is shown.

In principle, you'd want two objects which aren't equal to have different output when inspected. This isn't written in stone though, and some classes in the ruby standard libraries don't fullfil this property, like `Time`. When it comes to your own classes, maybe you've written a custom `#inspect` method?

Regarding `Time`, inspect only shows seconds, not fractions, but equality looks at fractions, so two time objects may not be equal but still look the same when inspected.

Regarding `Array`, if objects included in it can be not equal but look the same when inspected, this will cause the message to be displayed.

If you get this message even though the inspect outputs are different, something is wrong with the diff tool. MiniTest tries to do some educated guesses about which diff tool to use. You can inspect the chosen diff tool by printing `MiniTest::Assertions.diff`.

## On object equality

If the real issue is that your objects aren't equal when you expect them to be, you should look at how the `==` method is defined in the respective classes. The default implementation looks at the object ids given to each object when instantiated, which is probably not what you want if for example dealing with objects that represent database rows.

Comment: I didn't create custom #inspect methods on any object, and the weird thing is that I just tested everything on a different environment (OS X Yosemite), and everything works fine

Comment: What was the original system?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 (It's at the bottom of my question), and I used both Ruby 2.2 and 2.0

Comment: I'm sorry for not noticing that. Have you checked the output of `MiniTest::Assertions.diff`?

Comment: On which systems? Do the assertions behave the same way on ubuntu and os x? Is it just the message that differs?

Comment: Well, OS X doesn't show any failure messages, all test run normally. Both systems show diff -u as well

Comment: I'm stumped. Good luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the 2 objects' encoding instances are different. Use `encoding` and `force_encoding` to check :

```
puts obj1.encoding
puts obj2.encoding
```

Here is an example out put:

```
ISO-8859-1
ASCII-8BIT
```

In this case obj1's encoding instance is `ISO-8859-1` and obj2's encoding instance is `ASCII-8BIT`.
Then to convert obj1's encoding instance to `ASCII-8BIT` with `force_encoding`:

```
assert_equal(obj1.force_encoding(Encoding::ASCII_8BIT), obj2)
```

For more detail please check https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the following error:

```
No visible difference in the String#inspect output.
```

and tried @Protocol's answer - I got this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for "5930128297ebef21e1c7fd50":BSON::ObjectId
```

I'm using Mongoid, so at least for this issue, the solution was to call `to_s` on the `BSON` object and my string equality was what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match with your assertions, you can always convert both of the values to other types.

Ex:

```
assert_equal object_one.to_s, object_two.to_s
```